# Adding a number to the dock icon

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, badge, nsdocktile

Here is my code:

```
for (NSManagedObject *object in array) {
    if ([[object valueForKey:@"DueDate"] isLessThan:[NSDate date]]) {
        count++;
        NSLog(@"Looped");
        NSString *test = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [object valueForKey:@"DueDate"]];
        NSLog(@"%@", test);
    }
}
NSLog(@"%i", count);
NSDockTile *aTitle = [[NSApplication sharedApplication] dockTile];
[aTitle setBadgeLabel:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", count]];
```

For some reason this code is adding 8 to the dock icon when it should be 2

Comment: Aside: `isLessThan:` is intended for scripting support.

You should (IIRC) be using `if ([[object valueForKey:@"DueDate"] compare:[NSDate date]] == NSOrderedAscending)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On what grounds do you claim that it should be 2? You clearly have eight objects in the array whose due date is less than the current date (which you create a new object for each time through the loop, BTW).

What's the class of the values of these managed objects' `DueDate` property? (Don't look at your model for this—send the due date values `class` messages and log the results using `NSLog`.) It's possible that they're not NSDates, and that their `compare:` method is, instead of throwing an exception when asked to compare to an NSDate, simply returning nonsense.

Furthermore, why not include this is-less-than-X-date test as the predicate in the fetch request you're using to get these objects? Then (after making sure the due date values are NSDates) you could simply use the `count` of the array. That's assuming you aren't doing something else with the larger result array outside of the code you showed, of course.

Comment: The DueDate class NSLog returns __NSCFDate. so I take that is a NSDate?

Comment: Probably. The way to test that would be to log the class of `[NSDate date]` as well.

Comment: Then yes, they are both NSDates. Unless you can find another problem with it, I can only conclude that you have more dates that are earlier than the current date than you think you have. You can verify this by logging the dates themselves (`[array valueForKey:@"DueDate"]`).

Comment: No, `[array valueForKey:@"DueDate"]` does not return 8. It returns an array, unless `array` is not actually an array (in which case you either have named that variable poorly or have a memory-management problem). If you meant `count` being 8, nothing is wrong that I can see; you simply have eight dates that are less than the current date. Logging the items' `DueDate` (using the `[array valueForKey:@"DueDate"]` message) will prove that.